# Android custom theme not work on ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-theme

I have created a custom style

```
<style name="PrivatStyle" parent="Theme.Sherlock">

    <item name="android:textColor">@color/default_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/MyEditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/MyImageButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:expandableListViewStyle">@style/MyExpandableListViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/MyListViewStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="MyTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/default_text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/default_text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="MyEditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/default_text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="MyExpandableListViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ExpandableListView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/default_text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="MyListViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/default_text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="MyImageButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/default_text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/default_text_color</item>
</style>
```

In the manifest style of all activities are set to this

It works on TextView, Button, ListView, EditText but not work on ExpandableListView.

ExpandableListView is custom layouts from gropup.xml and child.xml.

If set style in gropup.xml and child.xml - all ok.